# Asp.Net WebForms designer auto update

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, designer, design-view

When we work over Asp.Net Forms (like .aspx pages), the source view gets updated automatically  when we edit designer.

On the other hand, disigner  is not bothered about changes made at mark-up/ sources.

We have to click **synchronise view** after every bit of change we make in source to be available in the desighner.

Are there some settings which could help or have to live with it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought these problems where gone with VS2008? What version of VS do you use?

The best way to go is **not** too use the designer at all. Seriously :-)  We archived that, by having a dedicated html & css person.

Comment: VS2008 is what i am using. It is not a problem, it is just lass efficient